# Как расположить слева снизу QPushButton pyqt5 Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Не могу разобраться с расположением кнопки в PyQt5, помогите, пожалуйста)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        #self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')

        btn = QPushButton('gg', self)
        #btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())

        self.setGeometry(480, 270, 1050, 650)
        self.setMinimumSize(600, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tooltips')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = main()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: прошу предоставить ваш код в студию, будем как-то помогать.

Comment: @S.Nick Написал код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте, что будет не понятно - спросите.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(480, 270, 1050, 650)
        self.setMinimumSize(600, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tooltips')    
    
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')

        label = QLabel('Hello World')
        
        btn = QPushButton('gg', self)
        btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())

        self.gridBox = QGridLayout()
        self.gridBox.addWidget(label, 0, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gridBox.addWidget(btn, 1, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.setLayout(self.gridBox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что обозначают 1 и 0 в строчке? self.gridBox.addWidget(btn, 1, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)

Comment: @Jairman  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-1

Comment: @Jairman да, но я почему-то разместил справа :) Замените `Qt.AlignRight`  на `Qt.AlignLeft`

Comment: это я понял сам)